# Rsync command not working in java

Tags: java, linux, git, ubuntu, rsync

The following commands works directly:

```
rsync -rtuc --delete-after --exclude '.git*' --filter 'protect .git/**/*' ~/some/source/ ~/some/destination/
```

But when run via java:

```
private Boolean syncFiles() {
            // Success flag default to true
            Boolean success = true;
            // Attempt sync repo
            try {
                ProcessBuilder runtimeProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(new String[]{
                    "rsync", "-rtuc","--delete-after", "--exclude", "'.git*'", "--filter", "'protect .git/**/*'", "~/some/source/", "~/some/destination/"
                });
                // Wait until process terminates
                int output = runtimeProcessBuilder.start().waitFor();
                // Determine if successful
                if (output == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Backup of " + getSource() + " to " + getDestination()
                            + " was successful");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: rsync returned error code: " + output);
                    success = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                success = false;
                System.out.println("Error:");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                Logger.getLogger(Rsync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return success;
    }
```

I get the error:

> Unknown filter rule: `'protect .git/**/*'' Error: rsync returned error
>   code: 1 rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(902)
>   [client=3.1.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell handles quoting before passing the parameters to the command.

The comes into play with this part of your command line:

```
 'protect .git/**/*'
```

The shell interprets this as the single parameter:

```
 protect .git/**/*
```

If the single quotes had not been there in the first place, the shell would have:

- interpreted it as two parameters (because of the space)
- expanded glob characters like "*"

The solution is to pass:

```
"protect .git/**/"
```

as one of your Java parameters, rather than `"'protect .git/**/*'"`.

You may have similar problems with `~`, which the shell will expand to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the solution is as follows:

The **ProcessBuilder** object needs to be initialised as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder runtimeProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(new String[]{
     "rsync", "-rtuc","--delete-after", "--filter", "protect .git", "--exclude", "'.git*'", "~/some/source/", "~/some/destination/"
});
```